# Defining dependencies between jQuery and jQuery UI does not prevent loading UI before jQuery itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

Maybe somebody was able to fix such issue?

**Questions :**

- Case # 1 - why IE loads jQuery UI before jQuery even though shim
  dependencies in Require JS forbid this?
  This question looks similar to mine - [Angular UI slider with Require JS fires before jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597552/angular-ui-slider-with-require-js-fires-before-jquery-ui)
- Case # 2 - if i load jQuery, jQuery UI and Require JS modules
  separately and specific module is dependent on jQuery UI why this
  module does not know that jQuery UI was already loaded before Require
  JS?

Here goes long description of the issue.

**Case # 1 - everything is a module of Require JS.**

In HTML i have :

```
<script 
    src="/scripts/libs/require.min.js"
    data-main="/scripts/application.js">
</script>
```

In application.js i have :

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        libsJQ: 'libs/jquery.min',
        libsUI: 'libs/jquery.ui.min',
        libsMouse: 'libs/jquery.mousewheel.min',
        modulesVideo: 'modules/video'
},
    shim: {

        libsUI: { deps: ['libsJQ'] },
        libsMouse: { deps: ['libsUI'] },
        modulesVideo: { deps: ['libsUI'] }
});
```

In modules/video.js i have :

```
define(function(require) {

    return {

        setup: function() {

            var s = this;

            s.link = $('.content-link');
            s.popup = $('.video');

            s.popup.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 500 },
                hide: { effect: 'fade', duration: 500 }
            });

            s.link.bind('click', function() {
                s.popup.dialog('open');
            });
        }
});
```

1) I am having Require JS that includes jQuery, jQuery UI and several modules dependent on them.

2) Some modules depend exactly on jQuery UI e.g. module that displays video in popup

3) If i try to load everything as modules of Require JS then in all browsers everything seems to be working fine, dependencies working but from time to time in IE i get such errors

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'easeOutQuad'
```

Which means that independently of shim dependencies sometimes in IE jQuery UI loads faster then jQuery

**Case # 2 - jQuery and jQuery UI need to be included before Require JS.**

In HTML i have :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/sonifi/scripts/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/sonifi/scripts/libs/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>

<script 
    src="<?php print sonifi_assets() ?>/scripts/libs/require.min.js"
    data-main="<?php print sonifi_assets() ?>/scripts/application.js">
</script>
```

In application.js i have :

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        libsMouse: 'libs/jquery.mousewheel.min',
        modulesVideo: 'modules/video'
});
```

Now i get this error in all browsers :

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://sonifi.web/themes/sonifi/scripts/jquery.js
Error: Script error for: jquery http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
Error: Load timeout for modules: modulesVideo
```

Which seems that Require JS wants to include jQuery as its module otherwise if it does not have config for jQuery but it has modules that depend on jQuery it tries to find it in absolutely wrong directory and of course cannot find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in my case i simply needed to increase timeout to give script a chance to load itself and only after this proceed to loading of its dependencies. If timeout is short enough Require JS simply stops loading of this script and goes to the next one.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds